# D2D1 and D3D11 interoperability issues in a multi-thread environment with a shared ID3D11Device

Tags: multithreading, direct3d, direct2d

Under D2D, I use the ID2D1RenderTarget object to draw line and image in separate threads, even render to another ID2D1RenderTarget object in the same thread, it always works fine.

But in the case of needing to support multi-threaded D3D / Media Foundation, I use global ID3D3d11Device and did an D2D/D3D interoperation.

if running only one thread, it works nice; bug if running two threads (each thread has a CDxRender window) at the same time, an error was reported, i don't known how to solve:

```
D2D DEBUG ERROR - An attempt to draw to an inaccessible target has been detected.
```

MFVerifDemo.exe debug breakpoint occur

```
Then press F5, continue to run:

D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: A Vertex Shader is always required when drawing, but none is currently bound. [ EXECUTION ERROR #341: DEVICE_DRAW_VERTEX_SHADER_NOT_SET]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: Rasterization Unit is enabled (PixelShader is not NULL or Depth/Stencil test is enabled and RasterizedStream is not D3D11_SO_NO_RASTERIZED_STREAM) but position is not provided by the last shader before the Rasterization Unit. [ EXECUTION ERROR #362: DEVICE_DRAW_POSITION_NOT_PRESENT]
D3D11: Removing Device.
```

1，Use d3d11createdevice to create a global variable _d3d11_device, and package the executecommandlist:

```
CComPtr<id3d11device>  _d3d11_device

HRESULT CreateD3DDevice(ID3D11Device** d3d11_device)
{
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> d3d11_immedContex;

    //Describe our Buffer
    DXGI_MODE_DESC bufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&bufferDesc, sizeof(DXGI_MODE_DESC));
    bufferDesc.Width = 0;
    bufferDesc.Height = 0;
    bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    bufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    bufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    bufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    bufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    //Create our _swap_chain1   
    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE , NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, NULL, NULL, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, d3d11_device, NULL, &d3d11_immedContex);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    CComPtr<ID3D11Multithread> D3DDevMT;
    hr = (*d3d11_device)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&D3DDevMT));
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
    D3DDevMT->SetMultithreadProtected(TRUE);

    return hr;
}
void ExecuteCommandList(CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext>    deferred_context)
{
    CComPtr<ID3D11CommandList> command_list;
    HRESULT hr = deferred_context->FinishCommandList(FALSE, &command_list);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL2(hr);

    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> immediate_context;
    _d3d11_device->GetImmediateContext(&immediate_context);

    if (immediate_context)
    {
        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> lck(_mutex);
        immediate_context->ExecuteCommandList(command_list, FALSE);
    }
}
```

2，  In window class "CDxRender", defines a series of member-variables：

```
const int Output_Width = 960;
const int Output_Height = 720;
const UINT32 fps = 50;

struct DefVertBuffer
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 pos;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4 color;
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 texCoord;
};

CComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1>        _swap_chain1;
CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext>    _deferred_context;
CComPtr<ID2D1Factory>           _d2d_factory;

CComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> _render_target_view;
CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D>        _back_texture2d;
CComPtr<IDXGISurface>           _back_dxgi_surface;
CComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget>      _back_render_target;
CComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap>            _back_d2d1_bitmap;

CComPtr<ID3D11SamplerState>     _sampler_state;
CComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout>      _input_layout;
CComPtr<ID3D11VertexShader>     _vertex_shader;
CComPtr<ID3D11PixelShader>      _pixel_shader;
CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>           _vert_buffer;
CComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>           _index_buffer;
```

3，The main implementation is as follows:

```
HRESULT CDxRender::InitD3d11()
{
    RECT client_rect;
    GetClientRect(&client_rect);
    DirectX::XMMATRIX WVP;
    WVP = DirectX::XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH(0.0f, static_cast<float>(client_rect.right - client_rect.left),  static_cast<float>(client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top), 0.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    //Create our _swap_chain1
    CComPtr<IDXGIFactory2> dxgi_factory2;
    HRESULT hr = GetDxgiFactoryFromD3DDevice(_d3d11_device, &dxgi_factory2);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    //Describe our _swap_chain1
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = { 0 };
    swapChainDesc.Width = client_rect.right - client_rect.left; // Match the size of the window.
    swapChainDesc.Height = client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top;
    swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM; // This is the most common swap chain format.
    swapChainDesc.Stereo = FALSE;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1; // Don't use multi-sampling.
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2; // Use double-buffering to minimize latency.
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL; // All Windows Store apps must use this SwapEffect.
    swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
    swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_NONE;
    swapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE;

    hr = dxgi_factory2->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(_d3d11_device, m_hWnd, &swapChainDesc, nullptr, nullptr, &_swap_chain1);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    D2D1_FACTORY_OPTIONS options;
    options.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION;
    hr = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, options, &_d2d_factory);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    hr = _d3d11_device->CreateDeferredContext(0, &_deferred_context);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufDs;
    memset(&bufDs, 0, sizeof(bufDs));
    bufDs.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufDs.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufDs.ByteWidth = sizeof(DefVertBuffer) * 4;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subData;
    std::vector<DefVertBuffer> temptBuffer;
    DefVertBuffer temptData;
    //  lb
    temptData.pos = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
    temptData.color = { 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
    temptData.texCoord = { 0.0f, 1.0f };
    temptBuffer.push_back(temptData);
    //  lt
    temptData.pos = { -1.0f,1.0f,0.0f };
    temptData.color = { 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
    temptData.texCoord = { 0.0f, 0.0f };
    temptBuffer.push_back(temptData);
    //  rt
    temptData.pos = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
    temptData.color = { 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
    temptData.texCoord = { 1.0f, 0.0f };
    temptBuffer.push_back(temptData);
    //  rb
    temptData.pos = { 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f };
    temptData.color = { 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
    temptData.texCoord = { 1.0f, 1.0f };
    temptBuffer.push_back(temptData);
    subData.pSysMem = temptBuffer.data();
    hr = _d3d11_device->CreateBuffer(&bufDs, &subData, &_vert_buffer);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
    unsigned __int32 indexBuff[] =
    {
        0,1,2,
        0,2,3
    };
    bufDs.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    bufDs.ByteWidth = sizeof(unsigned __int32) * 6;
    subData.pSysMem = indexBuff;
    hr = _d3d11_device->CreateBuffer(&bufDs, &subData, &_index_buffer);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    std::vector<D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC> layout;
    layout.push_back({ "POSITION",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT,0,0,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0 });
    layout.push_back({ "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 });
    layout.push_back({ "TEXCOORD",0,DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,0,28,D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,0 });

    hr = _d3d11_device->CreateInputLayout(layout.data(), layout.size(), g_VertexShader, ARRAYSIZE(g_VertexShader), &_input_layout);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    hr = _d3d11_device->CreateVertexShader(g_VertexShader, ARRAYSIZE(g_VertexShader), NULL, &_vertex_shader);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);
    hr = _d3d11_device->CreatePixelShader(g_PixelShader, ARRAYSIZE(g_PixelShader), NULL, &_pixel_shader);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC samplerDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&samplerDesc, sizeof(D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC));
    samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    samplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
    samplerDesc.MinLOD = 0;
    samplerDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

    hr = _d3d11_device->CreateSamplerState(&samplerDesc, &_sampler_state);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    return hr;
}

HRESULT CDxRender::Resize(const UINT32& w, const UINT32& h)
{
    _render_target_view = nullptr;
    _back_texture2d = nullptr;
    _back_dxgi_surface = nullptr;
    _back_d2d1_bitmap = nullptr;
    _back_render_target = nullptr;

    HRESULT hr = _swap_chain1->ResizeBuffers(2, w, h, DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, 0);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    hr = _swap_chain1->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&_back_texture2d);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    hr = _d3d11_device->CreateRenderTargetView(_back_texture2d, NULL, &_render_target_view);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    _deferred_context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &_render_target_view.p, NULL);

    hr = _back_texture2d->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&_back_dxgi_surface));
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

#if 1
    UINT dpi = GetDpiForWindow(m_hWnd);
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES props = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT, D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED), static_cast<float>(dpi), static_cast<float>(dpi));

    hr = _d2d_factory->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(_back_dxgi_surface, &props, &_back_render_target);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);

    float dpi_x = 0.f;
    float dpi_y = 0.f;
    _back_render_target->GetDpi(&dpi_x, &dpi_y);
    D2D1_SIZE_U src_sizeU = _back_render_target->GetPixelSize();
    D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES prop = D2D1::BitmapProperties(D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED), dpi_x, dpi_y);
    hr = _back_render_target->CreateBitmap(src_sizeU, prop, &_back_d2d1_bitmap);
    RETURN_ON_FAIL(hr);        
#endif

    return hr;
}

void CDxRender::PreRender(const UINT32& w, const UINT32& h)
{
    unsigned __int32 stride = sizeof(DefVertBuffer);
    unsigned __int32 offset = 0;
    _deferred_context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    _deferred_context->IASetIndexBuffer(_index_buffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
    _deferred_context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &_vert_buffer.p, &stride, &offset);
    _deferred_context->PSSetShader(_pixel_shader, 0, 0);
    _deferred_context->VSSetShader(_vertex_shader, 0, 0);
    _deferred_context->IASetInputLayout(_input_layout);
    _deferred_context->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &_sampler_state.p);
    _deferred_context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &_render_target_view.p, nullptr);

    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewPort;
    unsigned int viewPort_index = 1ui32;
    _deferred_context->RSGetViewports(&viewPort_index, &viewPort);
    viewPort.Width = static_cast<float>(w);
    viewPort.Height = static_cast<float>(h);
    viewPort.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewPort.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    _deferred_context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewPort);
}

void CDxRender::DrawScene()
{
    RECT client_rect;
    GetClientRect(&client_rect);

    PreRender(client_rect.right - client_rect.left, client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top);

    FLOAT bgArray[][4] =
    {
        { 1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.0f },
        { 0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.0f },
        { 0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.0f },
        { 1.f, 0.f, 1.f, 1.0f },
        { 1.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.0f },
        { 0.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.0f },
        { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.0f },
        { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.0f },
    };

    INT64 counter = (_capture_counter / (5 * fps)) % ARRAYSIZE(bgArray);
    FLOAT* bgColor = bgArray[counter];

#if 1
    CComPtr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> whiteBrush;
    _back_render_target->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(1.f, 1.f, 0.f, 1.f), &whiteBrush);

    // draw the text
    D2D1_SIZE_F border = _back_render_target->GetSize();

    float _offset_x = (rand() % 20 - 10) / 10.f;
    float _offset_y = (rand() % 20 - 10) / 10.f;

    _back_render_target->BeginDraw();
    _back_render_target->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(bgColor[0], bgColor[1], bgColor[2], bgColor[3]));
    _back_render_target->FillRectangle(D2D1::RectF(200 - 50 * _offset_y, 200 - 50 * _offset_x, 800 + 50 * (_offset_x + _offset_y) / 2, 600 - 50 * (_offset_x + _offset_y) / 2), whiteBrush);
    _back_render_target->DrawRectangle(D2D1::RectF(100 + 50 * _offset_x, 100 + 50 * _offset_y, border.width - 100 - 50 * (_offset_x + _offset_y) / 2, border.height - 100 + 50 * (_offset_x + _offset_y) / 2), whiteBrush, 10.f);

    hr = _back_render_target->EndDraw();///<------------will debug breakpoint here
#endif

    ExecuteCommandList(_deferred_context);

    //Present the backbuffer to the screen
    _swap_chain1->Present(0, 0);
}
```

4，PixelShader.hlsl:

```
struct PS_Input
{
    float4 pos:SV_POSITION;
    float4 color:COLOR;
    float2 texCoord:TEXCOORD;
};

Texture2D objTexture :register(t0);
SamplerState objSamplerState;

float4 main(PS_Input input) : SV_TARGET
{
    /*float4 retColor = 0;
    retColor = objTexture.Sample(objSamplerState, input.texCoord) * input.color;
    clip(retColor.a - 0.3);
    return retColor;*/
    return input.color;
}
```

5，VertexShader.hlsl:

```
struct VS_Input
{
    float4 pos:POSITION;
    float4 color:COLOR;
    float2 texCoord:TEXCOORD;
};

struct VS_Output
{
    float4 pos:SV_POSITION;
    float4 color:COLOR;
    float2 texCoord:TEXCOORD;
};

VS_Output main(VS_Input input)
{
    VS_Output output;
    output.pos = input.pos;/*mul(input.pos, WVP);*/
    output.color = input.color;
    output.texCoord = input.texCoord;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I don't see use of `ID3D11Multithread` in code. Do you enable multithreaded operation protection?

Comment: yes， Create ID3D11Device，then query ID3D11Multithread and SetMultithreadProtected(TRUE)

Comment: The solution is to share through idxgikeyedmutex, and D2D and D3D interoperate in a single thread.

Id3d11device that does not need global and cross thread sharing is actually needed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3darticles/surface-sharing-between-windows-graphics-apis